# Why is there "n" at end of plural of meter but not of "kilometer"

Tags: grammar-identification, declension

> Mit seinen rund 120 Metern ist er einer der höchsten Berge der Hauptstadt.

> Durch die Anlage konnten sie die Kommunikation im Osten bis zu 300 Kilometer weit hören. Heute findet auf dem 48 000 Quadratmeter großen Areal natürlich keine Spionage mehr statt.

Why in the first sentence we have "n" after Meter but we don't have at end of Kilometer or Quadratmeter?

Comment: "Mit seinen rund 11 Kilometern ist der Marianegraben ziemlich tief" as counter-example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the first sentence, "Metern" is [dative plural](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Meter), as required by "mit". The other examples are accusative, as measurements tend to be.

Comment: See e. g. [here](https://deutsch.heute-lernen.de/grammatik/der-die-das/meter/deklination) for a declination table. Dative is the only case requiring that "n" in plural.

Comment: Why do you claim that measurements are accusative? *"Sie konnten bis zu **300 km weit** hören." - "Sie konnten bis zu **mir** hören."* This is dative. Accusative is *"Sie konnten bis zu mich hören"* but this is wrong.

Comment: @Alina, I don’t claim that they always are. But it’s “eine*n* Kilometer weit”.

Comment: Note that *bis (zu)* is adverbial in *bis zu 300 Meter (weit)*, which means no case government, whereas the preposition *zu* governs the dative in *(bis) zu mir*. For the former, see [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bis_Adverb).

Comment: @Alina: Die Phrase, die du fett markiert hast, steht tatsächlich im Dativ, weil die Präposition *»zu«* zwingend den Dativ verlangt. Aber diese Phrase besteht aus mehreren Teilen, und am Ende steht das Wort *»weit«,* das nun aber vor sich etwas im Akkusativ braucht: *»Ich gehe **einen Meter** weit.« »Dorthin ist es nur **einen Steinwurf** weit.* Daher steht die von dir fett markierte Phrase inklusive dem Wort *»weit«* im Dativ, der Teil zwischen *»zu«* und *»weit«* aber im Akkusativ.

Answer (score 3):

> Why in the first sentence we have "n" after Meter but we don't have at end of Kilometer or Quadratmeter?

Because it comes before "Mit", a dative preposition. If it were nominative case (Das sind 120 Meter) it wouldn't have an "n".

In order to understand what I mean, you *must* first learn about:

1. ***[Cases](https://germanwithlaura.com/noun-cases/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20four%20cases%20in,%2C%20and%20genitive%20(possessive).)*** and ***[Prepositions](https://deutsch-coach.com/was-sind-praepositionen/)***. Otherwise it won't make sense.
2. ***[Plurals](https://www.sprachschule-aktiv-muenchen.de/der-plural-im-deutschen-regeln-pluralbildung-funktion-formen/#:%7E:text=Die%20meisten%20neutralen%20Nomen%20und,Wald%20%E2%80%93%20die%20W%C3%A4lder%2C%20etc.)***, which just you *must* memorize them as you learn new vocabulary and their genders.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong. It's not the two words that behave different. They live in different environments and that' why you see different behavior. Put them in the same grammatical environment, and you will see:

- The preposition *»mit«* requires dative case:

  > Mit **seinen rund 120 Metern** ist er einer der höchsten Berge der Hauptstadt.
  > Mit **nur rund 18 Kilometern** ist die Südosttangende in Wien die kürzeste Autobahn Österreichs.
- The adjective *»weit«,* when combined with a measurement, requires this measurement to be in accusative case:

> Sie konnten **300 Kilometer** weit hören.
> Markus kann **zwei Meter** weit spucken.

Note, that the preposition *»zu«* requires dative case. So, what is marked bold in the next two sentences is in dative case:

> Sie konnten bis zu **300 Kilometer weit** hören.
> Sie konnten bis zu **dem Waldrand** hören.

So, the whole part *»300 Kilometer weit«* is in dative case, but the inner part *»300 Kilometer«* is in accusative case. Then every word "sees" only its nextmost environment, so the word *»Kilometer«* sees only the accusative environment and is therefore in accusative case. That *»300 Kilometer«* is boxed inside a dative-thing does not matter. By this trick every word is happy: *»zu«* gets is dative companion (*»300 Kilometer weit«*) and *»weit«* gets its accusative companion (*»300 Kilometer«*).

Comment: *Zu* isn't always a preposition; it can be a part of *bis (zu)*, which is adverbial (doesn't govern case, with the meaning "at most"), as can be seen from the example *das kann (bis zu) einen Tag dauern*. Adverbial *bis (zu)* can even co-occur with prepositions that do govern case: *mit (bis zu) einem Jahr Verzögerung rechnen* vs. *verzögert sich um (bis zu) ein Jahr*.

Comment: @DavidVogt: You are right, *»zu«* can be an adverb (*»Die Tür ist zu«*), but then it has no companion at all. In your example it is still a preposition that requires a companion in dative case: correct: *»Der Ball ist bis zu **mir** gerollt.«* wrong: *»Der Ball ist bis zu mich gerollt.«* also wrong: *»Der Ball ist bis zu gerollt.«* In your example it's the word *»dauern«* inside this dative phrase that enforces *»einen Tag«* to be in accusative case. It's exactly the same situation as described in my answer.

Comment: 1) You conveniently ignored the last two examples that show that *mit, um* govern the case and *bis zu* is an optional MWE with the meaning "at most". 2) *das dauert (bis zu) einen Tag* certainly doesn't have *dauern* inside *bis zu*. 3) For reference, see the Duden grammar, 9th edition, paragraphs 871 and 921 (or the 10th edition, 1446 and 1504).

Comment: @DavidVogt  (and at Hubert): I am a little torn. Possible that the preposition and the conjunction are in a process of "hybridization"? Because: "Das kann bis zu drei Jahre dauern" doesn't require a dative for me; but perhaps formal grammar would require "bis zu drei Jahren", or we assume an omitted "lang". Or "Der Behälter fasst bis zu zehn Liter." Should actually be "Litern"? Maybe. "Der Oktopus hat bis zu neun Arme." Nicht "bis zu neun Armen", oder? Sonst denkt man noch, der will irgendwo hin ;-). But not entirely clear to me. Perhaps my native speaker ear is sloppy.

Comment: So I would make a distinction between "er läuft jeden Tag (bis) zum Bahnhof", where the "bis" is, as the Duden states, semantically and grammatically optional: Here, clearly a dative is required. But "er läuft jeden Tag bis zu zehn Kilometer" does not require one, in my opinion, and this use of "zu" is quite different. (Of course one can again invent an omitted "weit" though.)

Comment: One can stretch an argument that it indicates a direction as well (an abstract one towards a value), but if we use the dative here we must be careful not to create a *Stilblüte* ("*wo*hin will der!?"): "Er läuft bis zu drei Kilometern" is close to "er läuft bis zu den Drei Quellen" (or whatever). Quite a different use that may well profit from a different case.

Comment: As an aside, "Sie konnten zu 300 Kilometer weit hören" is ungrammatical for me. The "bis" is required here which indicates that "bis zu" for amounts is not the same use case as "bis zu" for locations as in "er läuft [optional bis] zum Bahnhof".